# Is it possible to make fullcalendar.io to selectable by square in weekView?

Tags: jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-selectable

I am making a calendar web-app with fullcalendar.io. sometimes I want to create event or block my schedule same time for some days repeatedly. Can I tweak fullcalendar and make it possible to drag and selected in square?

for example drag start from 2pm to 6pm monday and expand this to friday in right direction. when I do this in normal fullcalendar, it select from monday 2pm to friday 6pm. it is not square. I do not want to select from 6pm to next day 2pm repeatedly.

Is it possible? if it is, how can I do this?